# ¿Cómo pasar una lista de diccionario a una matriz numpy?

Tags: python, lista, algoritmos, numpy, diccionarios

Gente estoy trabajando con el algoritmo BFS
El codigo me arroja una lista de diccionario que me gustaría arreglar en una matriz

Lo que obtengo del código es lo siguiente

> ```
> {1: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 2: 3, 8: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 9: 7, 5: 8, 10: 9}
> {2: 0, 8: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 9: 4, 5: 5, 10: 6, 1: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1}
> {3: 0, 4: 1, 9: 2, 5: 3, 10: 4, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1}
> {4: 0, 9: 1, 5: 2, 10: 3, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1}
> {5: 0, 10: 1, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1}
> {6: 0, 7: 1, 2: 2, 8: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 9: 6, 5: 7, 10: 8, 1: -1}
> {7: 0, 2: 1, 8: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 9: 5, 5: 6, 10: 7, 1: -1, 6: -1}
> {8: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 9: 3, 5: 4, 10: 5, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1}
> {9: 0, 5: 1, 10: 2, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1}
> {10: 0, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1}
> ```

La idea es generar una matriz 10 x 10 ordenada. Si notan las filas están organizadas pero las columnas no, están en desorden de acuerdo a la lista.

Intenté con este arreglo, pero no me salió en absoluto

> ```
> import collections
>
> def dic_to_matrix(dic):
>     dic = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items()))
>     for item in dic.items():
>         matrix.append(item)
>         print(matrix)
>
> matrix=[]
> dic = (BFS(graph, node))
> dic_to_matrix(dic)
> ```

Aparece esto

> ```
> [(1, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1), (4, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1), (4, -1), (5, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1), (4, -1), (5, -1), (6, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1), (4, -1), (5, -1), (6, -1), (7, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1), (4, -1), (5, -1), (6, -1), (7, -1), (8, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1), (4, -1), (5, -1), (6, -1), (7, -1), (8, -1), (9, -1)]
> [(1, -1), (2, -1), (3, -1), (4, -1), (5, -1), (6, -1), (7, -1), (8, -1), (9, -1),
> ```

¿Alguno sabe cómo podría organizar ese diccionario en una matriz cuadrada y ordenada?

La idea es que quede algo así (que se organice de acuerdo a lo que hay en el diccionario, en orden)

[image: Respuesta esperada]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado que esperas lograr?

Comment: No sé si se ve la respuesta que puse, quería editar el post y me equivoqué. Algo más o menos como eso: una matriz cuadrada a partir de la lista de diccionarios. Es eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco (pues he visto tus anteriores preguntas sobre este tema y la evolución del código), lo que obtienes como resultado de tu llamada a BFS no es una lista como dices, sino un diccionario (sospecha confirmada porque la variable en que lo recoges se llama `dic`).

Este diccionario sería como el siguiente:

```
dic = {
    1: {1: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 2: 3, 8: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 9: 7, 5: 8, 10: 9},
    2: {2: 0, 8: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 9: 4, 5: 5, 10: 6, 1: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1},
    3: {3: 0, 4: 1, 9: 2, 5: 3, 10: 4, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
    4: {4: 0, 9: 1, 5: 2, 10: 3, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
    5: {5: 0, 10: 1, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1},
    6: {6: 0, 7: 1, 2: 2, 8: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 9: 6, 5: 7, 10: 8, 1: -1},
    7: {7: 0, 2: 1, 8: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 9: 5, 5: 6, 10: 7, 1: -1, 6: -1},
    8: {8: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 9: 3, 5: 4, 10: 5, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1},
    9: {9: 0, 5: 1, 10: 2, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
   10: {10: 0, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1}
}
```

Para convertirlo en un array numpy, que es lo que preguntas, la solución más simple es dejar que Pandas lo haga por tí:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

¡Funciona mágicamente! El dataframe resultante es así:

```
>>> print(df)
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1    0  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
2    3   0  -1  -1  -1   2   1  -1  -1  -1
3    5   2   0  -1  -1   4   3   1  -1  -1
4    6   3   1   0  -1   5   4   2  -1  -1
5    8   5   3   2   0   7   6   4   1  -1
6    1  -1  -1  -1  -1   0  -1  -1  -1  -1
7    2  -1  -1  -1  -1   1   0  -1  -1  -1
8    4   1  -1  -1  -1   3   2   0  -1  -1
9    7   4   2   1  -1   6   5   3   0  -1
10   9   6   4   3   1   8   7   5   2   0
```

Si lo que has obtenido no es exactamente lo que esperabas si no su traspuesta, basta que hagas luego `df = df.T` para corregirlo.

Este resultado no es un array numpy, sino un dataframe Pandas, pero ya que Pandas usa "por debajo" numpy, es muy sencillo extraer el array subyacente. Se encuentra en `df.values`:

```
>>> array = df.values
>>> print(type(array))
numpy.ndarray
>>> print(array)
[[ 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 3  0 -1 -1 -1  2  1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 5  2  0 -1 -1  4  3  1 -1 -1]
 [ 6  3  1  0 -1  5  4  2 -1 -1]
 [ 8  5  3  2  0  7  6  4  1 -1]
 [ 1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 2 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  0 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 4  1 -1 -1 -1  3  2  0 -1 -1]
 [ 7  4  2  1 -1  6  5  3  0 -1]
 [ 9  6  4  3  1  8  7  5  2  0]]
```

Por cierto que este método funciona igualmente si tu variable `dic` es en realidad una lista de diccionarios, sólo que en ese caso el `df` que obtienes es el transpuesto del aquí mostrado (cambia filas por columnas).

Comment: Amigo, sí es así pero el orden de las filas se revuelve demasiado. Empieza fila diez, después nueve y después la tres. El orden de las columnas está perfecto pero las columnas aún no.

Comment: @Andres No entiendo... Creo que este resultado es exactamente el mismo que pones en la imagen en tu pregunta, sólo que "transpuesto". Es decir, lo que en tu imagen de la excel aparece como primera fila, en mi resultado es la primera columna. Lo que aparece en la segunda fila, es la segunda columna, y supongo que el resto seguirá coincidiendo. Confírmame que es así, y edito la respuesta para añadir más claramente lo de `df.T` que te permite transponer el resultado (aunque ya lo había mencionado)

Comment: Ahhh sí, tienes toda la razón. Sí, con la traspuesta ya quedaría exacta. No me había fijado en eso  Lo que pasa es que no sé si a partir de ahí el código está fallando porque importo pandas y me sale error, de hecho muchos errores

Comment: Para poder importar pandas tienes que tenerlo instalado, claro está. No viene por defecto, pero ya que en tu pregunta mencionabas Numpy, di por hecho que o bien usabas Anaconda (una distribución de Python para cómputo científico en la que es muy fácil añadir paquetes como numpy, pandas, etc.) o bien sabías como instalar paquetes adicionales.

Comment: Sí claro, ya pandas está instalado pero por alguna razón presenta error.

Comment: Ya entendí por qué no me funcionaba, pandas. La entrada eran muchos diccionarios (en mi caso) y lo que necesitaba era meter todos esos en un sólo diccionario. Gracias

Comment: Ahora que lo hice yo me pregunto por qué a ti se te ordena como debe ser y a mi no jaja

Comment: Pandas se basa en las claves de los diccionarios para crear su dataframe. Asegúrate de que el diccionario que le pasas a `pd.DataFrame()` tiene por claves `1, 2, 3,` etc. como en mi variable `dic`, y que para cada clave, el valor contiene otro diccionario, y que éste sea el apropiado para la correspondiente clave. El orden en que aparezcan las claves dentro del diccionario no importa, pues Pandas las reordenará por su valor numérico (1,2,3...), lo que sí importa es que cada clave tenga asociado su valor correcto.

Comment: Ah entiendo, tu creaste otro diccionario a partir de mi salida, y una vez con las claves correctas ya panda lo corre común y corriente, como debería ser. Porque en un principio yo copié y pegué el diccionario que tu anexaste y no salía lo mismo

Comment: @Andres Yo creía que tu salida era ya un diccionario (me refiero a la salida de la función, no a lo que se imprime por pantalla). Simplemente hice una variable `dic` y la inicialicé con lo que yo creía que salía de tu función. Si en vez de ese diccionario tu función retornase una lista (de diccionarios), también funcionaría.

Comment: Pues el tipo es un diccionario, efectivamente. Es que como soy muy nuevo en esto de programar no sé expresarme pero sí, type lo imprime como `dict` y no como `list`. También pensé que pandas trabajaría con esa lista de diccionarios pero no, arroja muchos errores (busqué y a mucha gente le pasa pero no se halla solución) entonces cuando observé cómo habías escrito la entrada (todo dentro de un mismo diccionario) intenté copiando y pegándolo como lo pusiste tu y me funcionó. De ahí cuando te dije que no me había dado la misma matrix

Answer (score 1):

A ver si es esto lo que quieres:

```
entrada = [{1: 0, 6: 1, 7: 2, 2: 3, 8: 4, 3: 5, 4: 6, 9: 7, 5: 8, 10: 9},
           {2: 0, 8: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 9: 4, 5: 5, 10: 6, 1: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1},
           {3: 0, 4: 1, 9: 2, 5: 3, 10: 4, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
           {4: 0, 9: 1, 5: 2, 10: 3, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
           {5: 0, 10: 1, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1},
           {6: 0, 7: 1, 2: 2, 8: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 9: 6, 5: 7, 10: 8, 1: -1},
           {7: 0, 2: 1, 8: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 9: 5, 5: 6, 10: 7, 1: -1, 6: -1},
           {8: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 9: 3, 5: 4, 10: 5, 1: -1, 2: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1},
           {9: 0, 5: 1, 10: 2, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1},
           {10: 0, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1, 4: -1, 5: -1, 6: -1, 7: -1, 8: -1, 9: -1}]

matrix = [[dicc[n] for n in range(1, len(dicc) + 1)] for dicc in entrada]
```

Con esto la salida será:

```
[[0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 4, 7, 9],
 [-1, 0, 2, 3, 5, -1, -1, 1, 4, 6],
 [-1, -1, 0, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, 2, 4],
 [-1, -1, -1, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, 1, 3],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1],
 [-1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 0, 1, 3, 6, 8],
 [-1, 1, 3, 4, 6, -1, 0, 2, 5, 7],
 [-1, -1, 1, 2, 4, -1, -1, 0, 3, 5],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 2],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0]]
```

y podrás acceder a los elementos individualmente poniendo `matrix[nºfila][nºcolumna]`

Comment: No amigo, la idea es que quede una matriz cuadrada de la siguiente manera. Voy a agregarla a la publicación

Comment: Acabo de editar tu pregunta, ya que al intentar añadir la respuesta esperada por error lo has hecho editando mi respuesta, en vez de tu pregunta.

Comment: @Andres acabo de cambiar completamente la respuesta ahora sabiendo lo que buscas. A ver si es esto.

Comment: Bro ¿tengo que cambiar unicamente el nombre de la variable entrada por la que tengo, cierto? es que me aparece este error `matrix = [[dicc[n] for n in range(1, len(dicc) + 1)] for dicc in O]
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: Viendo la respuesta de abulafia, he visto que no tienes un lista de diccionarios sino un diccionario. En ese caso tendrías que hacerlo así matrix = [[dicc[n] for n in range(1, len(dicc) + 1)] for dicc in entrada.values()], pero de todas formas si lo que buscas es un array numpy (cuando leí la primera vez la pregunta, creo que no lo ponía... o no me fijé) utiliza la respuesta de abulafia, que es exactamente lo que hace, esta lo que te devuelve es una lista anidada.

Comment: Sí, es una lista de diccionarios. Abulafia la reescribió como un diccionario ¿de casualidad sabes cómo hacer de una lista de diccionarios un diccionario? tal cual como puso abulafia